# SQL SELECT top row and aggregate counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I can't wrap my head around this. I have a client-staff communication system. On the admin side, I'm trying to retrieve a list of users, which contains total number of messages, total new messages, last message date, last message for that user.

A bit of logic:

- sender or receiver value of 0, means staff sent or received it.
- sender or receiver value of X, means user with ID value of X received or sent it.

Sample Data:

```
ID  |date                   |new    |sender |receiver   |message
----+-----------------------+-------+-------+-----------+------------
1   |2013-12-22 08:19:12    |1      |2      |0          |Hello
2   |2013-12-22 08:23:19    |0      |0      |2          |Hello There
3   |2013-12-22 08:23:19    |0      |0      |4          |Hello There
4   |2013-12-22 10:09:44    |1      |2      |0          |The latest message
```

Desired Output:

```
user ID |total_messages |total_new  |latest_date            |latest_messsage
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2       |3              |2          |2013-12-22 10:09:44    |The latest message
4       |1              |0          |2013-12-22 08:23:19    |Hello There
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Try to avoid using magic numbers like `0` for special meanings. If no user sent the message, the value should be `NULL` instead to indicate absence of a user. This also makes filtering and joining easier, and doesn't break declarative referential integrity.

Answer (score 1):

Split the logic of selecting the first row and the aggregate rows in two queries and UNION the results.

```
SELECT TOP 1 --columns-- 
FROM yourTable

UNION ALL

SELECT --columns-- 
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY --columns--
```

(without more details about the table structure or what is the desired output, this is the best answer I can come up with)

Comment: This would not specify that X user has X results, I was thinking more on a JOIN because the latest message and latest date have to belong to that user.

Comment: Can you edit the question and also add desired output?

Comment: I did. Maybe I'm ignorant to the process but styling the spacing on stackoverflow needs some work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your database tables. but I can quess you have a message table and a user table.

```
SELECT 
    [userId], 
    (SELECT 
         count(*)
     FROM messages
     WHERE u.userId = messages.UserId) AS totalMessages, 
    (SELECT
         TOP 1 [TimeStamp]
     FROM messages
     WHERE messages.UserId = u.UserId
     ORDER BY messages.MessageId DESC), 
    (SELECT
         TOP 1 [Message]
     FROM messages
     WHERE messages.UserId = u.UserId
     ORDER BY messages.MessageId DESC)
FROM users u
```

You can compute sender and receiver columns like this.

Answer (score 1):

Since it doesn't seem to matter whether a user sent or received for your totals, one way you could do this is by listing message data by user (sender or receiver) in a single column (I used a CTE), then using that set for aggregation and `JOIN` it to itself to get `latest_message`

```
WITH Users_CTE AS
(
  SELECT sender AS user_id, ID, new, date, message
  FROM Messages
  WHERE sender <> 0
  UNION
  SELECT receiver AS user_id, ID, new, date, message
  FROM Messages
  WHERE receiver <> 0
)

SELECT m.user_id, m.total_messages, m.total_new, m.latest_date, u.message AS latest_message
FROM (SELECT user_id
        , COUNT(*) AS total_messages
        , SUM(new) AS total_new
        , MAX(date) AS latest_date
      FROM Users_CTE
      GROUP BY user_id) AS m
  INNER JOIN Users_CTE AS u ON u.user_id = m.user_id
    AND u.date = m.latest_date
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/85c87/3)